# Characteristic chords of a mode/scale

Tags: chords, scales, chord-theory, modes

What makes a chord a characteristic chord of a mode? Apparently, the characteristic chords of Lydian is I and II, why is that? Why not, for instance, vii, as Lydian is the only mode that contains a vii?

[image]

Comment: What source are you using  for this information?

Comment: If my calculations are correct, you can only play 6 different notes with two triads, so whichever two triads you choose, one of the seven notes is left out. If you make it II 6, then the missing note gets exposed? It's an approximation and opinion anyway. If you read the text surrounding this chart in wherever it was taken from, you may find a description of what the chart is meant for, who made it etc.

Comment: @Tim https://youtu.be/AAxZzySz_UE?t=403

Comment: Have a listen to  the whole thing. I don't necessarily agree with his dark/darker ideas, though. Seems somewhat subjective.

Comment: Wait, so there is no such thing as a characteristic chord?

Answer (score 1):

There is never one chord isolated  characteristic for a mode. It‘s always the position in a progression and its specific function.

I just  can tell you some examples - knowing there are more others. I‘ll choose the key of C major.

1. D- Dorian versus d-minor: the major sixth of the Dorian scale is the major 3rd of the IV. So in dorian you may think we are in d-minor but then the „subdominant“ would be G,B,D = a major chord, but we would expect a minor iv, so the characteristic chord is the IV degree.
2. Mixolydian: similar to G-major, I = G,B,D IV = C,E,G but the characteristic chord is built by the minor 7th which is the minor 3rd of the expected dominant chord which now is a minor v.

So we could go through all modes:
 As you see I would list  all cadences  and compare them with the major I IV V I and minor i-iv-V-i.

1. Dorian: i **IV** v i versus minor
2. Mixolydian: I IV **v** I and also **bVII** versus major

In the same way you can compare all other modes and find zhe characteristic chords.